# How do I connect buttons from my xib file to the UIViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have a view controller with a scrollview at the bottom to scroll some thumbnails. When the user taps on a thumbnail I want the larger version to appear in a `UIImageView` on the centre of the screen. My `UIScrollView` has a `UIView` inside named *content*. Content is initiated from a xib file. My xib file has the thumbnails (these are actually buttons). Everything works fine. The scrollview loads and scrolls but I'm not sure how to connect the buttons from that xib file to my view controller. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have exact information about the structure of your XIB(s), but supposing that your view controller instantiates this XIB (and sets itself as the owner):

1. Make sure to set the class of the "File Owner" in the XIB to the class of your view controller (Select "File Owner" on the left and open the 3rd inspector tab on the right).
2. Ctrl-drag from your button(s) to the implementation body of your view controller.

Of course, you can also do this in code (via 
[`addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget:action:forControlEvents:)).